# Need some help calculating averages from a list of integers

Tags: python

[Here is what I have so far.]

```
import statistics

print ("Type '0' at any time to end program.")

my_numbers=[]

while True:

    try:
        x=int(input("Enter a positive integer. "))
        my_numbers.append(x)
        while x<0:
            print ("Enter a POSITIVE integer.")
            x=int(input("Enter a positive integer. "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid character entered. Enter a positive integer.")
    if x==0:
        print ('Your mean is',statistics.mean(my_numbers))
        print ('Your median is',statistics.median(my_numbers))
        print ('Your range is',max(my_numbers) - min(my_numbers))
        break
```

Essentially the code needs to ask for positive integers and calculate the mean, median, and range of them after the user inputs "0". The code also needs to not allow the user to input non-positive integers. I have two problems.

- The final calculations are including negative integers and zero. I need negative numbers and zero to be excluded from the final calculations. Note: Decimals aren't being included in the final calculations, for some reason.
- Non-integers return the error "NameError: name 'x' is not defined" in line 13.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Put your code in the question itself, as text, formatted as code.

Comment: Also, there doesn't seem to be a question in your question. Please see [ask].

Comment: Looks more like a "please do my work" post than an actual question.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere or do you just want us to do your work for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456135/calculate-the-mean-median-and-range-of-a-list-of-user-inputted-integers looks like your classmate already asked about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for such questions, making Python easier to start with for next visitors of this page.

- final calculation includes negative integers and zero because you append it to your list before testing it.`my_numbers.append(x)` should be after and outside your `while` test such as :
- NameError is raised for user input such as string or characters when
  those string or character are not resolvable to an integer (like a predefined Python variable). You
  should catch `NameError` as well as you did for `ValueError`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `my_numbers.append(x)` down the while loop.
2. What you need is to catch the [NameError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `my_numbers.append(x)` when you get a valid x.

Answer (score 0):

> The final calculations are including negative integers and zero. I
>   need negative numbers and zero to be excluded from the final
>   calculations.

Because you are appending the input before the check `while x<0`.

**Solution**: move the appending statement `my_numbers.append(x)` below while block.

> Note: Decimals aren't being included in the final calculations, for
>   some reason.

The int(x) converts the decimals/floats to intergers i.e. technically you don't have any decimals.

**Solution**: use `float()` instead of `int()`

> Non-integers return the error "NameError: name 'x' is not defined" in
>   line 13.

Passing a characeter that cannot be converted (type casted) to interger, using `int()` raises `NameError`.

**Solution**: You need to handle this expception same as you're expecting `ValueError`.

---

The final code:

```
import statistics

print ("Type '0' at any time to end program.")

my_numbers=[]

while True:
    try:
        x=int(input("Enter a positive integer. "))        
        while x<0:
            print ("Enter a POSITIVE integer.")
            x=int(input("Enter a positive integer. "))
    my_numbers.append(x)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid character entered. Enter a positive integer.")
    except NameError:
        print ("Invalid character entered. Enter a positive integer.")
    if x==0:
        print ('Your mean is',statistics.mean(my_numbers))
        print ('Your median is',statistics.median(my_numbers))
        print ('Your range is',max(my_numbers) - min(my_numbers))
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import statistics

print ("Type '0' at any time to end program.")

my_numbers=[]       #list to hold integer input from the user


while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter a positive integer. "))
        while x<0:
            print("Enter a POSITIVE integer.")
            x = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

except ValueError:
    print ("Invalid character entered. Enter a positive integer.")

if (x==0): 
    print ('Your mean is: ',statistics.mean(my_numbers))
    print ('Your median is: ',statistics.median(my_numbers))
    print ('Your range is: ',max(my_numbers) - min(my_numbers))
    break

# my_numbers.append(x) is moved down the loop
# the value of x will only be appended to my_numbers if it is valid input
my_numbers.append(x)
```